# Automate work in PCOMM (v6.0) using Python

Tags: python, automation

I need a python-driven tool or python library that will allow me to automate a running session in the Personal Communication 6.0 emulator (PCOMM) on Win10 x64.

It would be perfect if it worked exactly the same as Visual Basic here=>[HOST ACCESS CLASS LIBRARY (HACL) API IN IBM PCOMM](https://community.ibm.com/community/user/ibmz-and-linuxone/blogs/mahua-chanda/2021/09/01/host-access-class-library-hacl-api-in-ibm-pcomm-pa).

Does anyone know how to go about this?

I tried use python library like p3270 or p5250 but it didn't work as it should and I could connect only with wc3270 tool. Now I have to work with only PCOMM emulator.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using [pywin32](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/).

Here is a sample. I'm using [autoit](https://github.com/jacexh/pyautoit) to launch and close the window (you may choose to do something else) and using a workstation profile (.ws file) rather than manually establishing host connections etc.

```py
from win32com import client   # pip install pywin32
import autoit                 # pip install pyautoit

# launch PCOMM -- can do this manually
pid = autoit.run(f'"{pcomm_exe_path}" "{ws_file_path}"')  
# instances are named 'Session A', 'Session B',... as they are created
session_name = 'A'

# create session object
autECLSession_obj = client.Dispatch("PCOMM.autECLSession")  

# connect to the existing PCOMM window
autECLSession_obj.SetConnectionByName(session_name)  
# autECLSession provides instances of several automation objects
autECLPS_obj = autECLSession_obj.autECLPS
# these can also be initialized on their own--refer to definitions & diagrams in the manual
# autECLPS is the primary class for interacting with PCOMM ("PS" = Presentation Space)
...

# may use argument names or omit them
some_text = autECLPS_obj.GetText(Row=5, Col=10, GetLen=1)  

# SendKeys sends keystrokes/commands using 'mnemonic keywords'
# this line sends the letters "load" and then the enter key
autECLPS_obj.SendKeys("load[enter]", 1, 2)
...

autoit.win_kill(f"Session {session_name}")  # close window
```

Refer to IBM's [Host Access Automation class online documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/personal-communications/15.0?topic=library-host-access-class-automation-objects) for PCOMM versions 12.0-15.0, or this [full reference manual PDF](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/SSEQ5Y_6.0.0/com.ibm.pcomm.doc/books/pdf/host_accessV60.pdf) for version 6.0. I do not know if there are any significant differences between 6.0 and later versions (I am using 14.0)

Notes:

- Not all function argument names align with the documentation. I don't know where the discrepancy is coming from but you can see argument names in Python using `inspect.signature(autECLPS_obj.SomeFunc)`
- Accessing `autECLSession.CommStarted` property crashes Python without exception if the communication has not yet been started, at least for me.
- It's not possible to interact with the emulator's Windows menu using the IBM Automation class. So while it is possible to perform print command via `autECLPS_obj.SendKeys("[printps]")`, I use autoit to interact with the subsequent Windows File Explorer "Save As" dialog to provide a filename. Not sure if there is another way to print without the Save As window...
- On my emulator, pressing the escape key frees the cursor if input is inhibited. I had to check my keyboard configuration in PCOMM to find that the escape key is sending the command `"[sys attn]"`. Doing this programmatically looks like `autECLPS_obj.SendKeys("[sys attn]")`